# Strip prefix of dependency in makefile rule target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which is designed to get some datasets from the web and unzip them into folders (given by the archive names). Unfortunately, the archives on the website are grouped within a folder structure. For example, if I want `dataset.tar.gz`, which is part of set `DIR1`, I call wget with: `www.example.com/DIR1/dataset.tar.gz`.

This is then downloaded to `dataset.tar.gz`, which I can then extract with `tar -xzf`. My makefile for this is currently:

```
URL = www.example.com
FILES = DIR1/something.url DIR2/another.url
FOLDERS = $(notdir $(patsubst %.url, %, $(FILES)) )

%.url: # do nothing

%.tar.gz : %.url
    wget -q $(URL)/$<

% : %.tar.gz
    tar -xzf $<

all: $(FOLDERS)
```

Unfortunately, the target for the rule `%.tar.gz : %.url` does not resolve to (e.g.) `something.tar.gz`, but to `DIR1/something.tar.gz`, even though it produces the expected file.

This causes problems when I rerun the makefile, as it does not detect `something.tar.gz` (as it is looking for `DIR1/something.tar.gz`), and redownloads the dataset, wasting time and bandwidth.

Is there any way of stripping prefixes/directories from makefile targets, i.e. removing `DIR1` from the rule `%.tar.gz : %.url`, in order that the makefile correctly checks to see if it is satisfied?

Comment: Can you not just tell `wget` to download it to the current directory?

Comment: the problem is that wget does exactly that; if I ask it to download `http://www.example.com/DIR1/something.tar.gz`, it will download it to `./something.tar.gz`. The problem is that the target of the makefile rule includes `DIR1`, so is expecting `./DIR1/something.tar.gz`. For various important reasons, I don't want to include the directory once I've downloaded the datasets, so I'm a little stuck.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread. Yes, you can do what you want. I'll write something up in a little bit.

Comment: So looking at this again I see what I misread what you were saying. That's not what this makefile does. This makefile sets up `FOLDERS = something another` and then has `all: something another` and `something : something.tar.gz`, etc. It *doesn't* have the `DIR1` components in the targets at all. So what *exactly* is the actual problem here and is this *actually* the makefile you are using? Also that makefile didn't work for me at all (in a test) until I used `%.url: ; # Do nothing` to actually give the `%.url` target an empty recipe.

Comment: This is a simplification of the makefile I'm using. It's very possible that I've made a mistake in simplifying it. I'll post a (broken, but 'working') version when I can.